# Show latest notifications in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

There is a way to show past notifications in Windows 8?

If for example I was away from keyboard for 30 minutes, I want to see what happened, in a glance.

Or I have to watch the "alert bubbles" in the start menu? (less immediate)

Comment: One would think the Event Log would contain anything that caused a notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No

This is a much commented on quirk in Windows 8. It is currently not supported by [the framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853947/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-windows-8-notifications) (notifications can be missed) and it has raised an immeasurable number of posts [to various web boards](http://owened.co.nz/windows-8-needs-a-notification-centre).

Comment: Is this still the case in 2014 with Windows 8.1? My Surface Pro is sleeping and makes notification sounds. Later I wake it up to see what was so important and nothing to see.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Windows 8 doesn't have a unified notification center or something. So no notification history feature in Windows 8 as of yet.