# Are there any applications to aggregate Windows 8 notifications?

Tags: windows-8, notifications

I see that there [isn't a built in way to see recent notifications within Windows 8](https://superuser.com/q/496836/44248), but are there any Growl-like applications which can process and store these notifications, since Windows won't do it?

Comment: No; it is [not possible to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853947/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-windows-8-notifications).

Comment: I see that the post says that it's not possible to view a history of notifications, but is it possible to collect notifications as they happen?

Comment: Event log maybe?

Comment: As per Raymond Chen on that StackOverflow post, "The notification guidelines specifically say that notifications should be designed so that users can miss them without negative conseqences." As for whether "it is possible to collect notifications as they happen" by a 3rd party app, an unsupported hack may work as Raymond said, but I haven't come across anything of the nature yet. It will take time for devs to even figure out how to access/capture the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Growl for Windows:  http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx

Comment: Does Growl for Windows do anything with built-in notifications?  I'm not seeing the Windows 8 notifications interacting with Growl in any way